# How to calculate 30 days back from today using Calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I want to calculate the date 30 days back from today's date.

```
public void dateSetup(){
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calReturn = Calendar.getInstance();
        jDate_timeOfExpectedReturn1.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
        calReturn.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
        jDate_timeOfLoan1.setText(dateFormat.format(calReturn.getTime()));
    }
```

Above you can see that I'm extracting today date using `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();`

How do I calculate the date of 30 days before the extracted date?

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use `add()` method with `-30` days

```
 calReturn.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed it after posting the question.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `-30` which will be subtraction.

```
calReturn.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a **negative number** in `add()` method as `-30`, which will work like `date+(-30)` ==> `date-30`